# Returning undefined from mySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I know the database is connecting with the code as, when i `console.log(res)` with the code below it is returning the correct data,

```
const orm={
    selectAll(){
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM burgers', (err,res) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(res)
            return res;
        });
    },
```

Yet when i `console.log(burgers)` from this function in the code below it is returning an undefined

```
app.get(`/`, function (req, res) {
    const burgers = orm.selectAll();
    console.log(burgers)

    res.render(`index`, burgers);
});
```

I understand this may be a very simple answer but i personally just cannot work it out any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

selectAll is using a callback style method inside it. You can not get the response syncronously. You need to either pass the callback to selectAll or change it to use promise like this

```
function selectAll() {
  return new Promise((reoslve, reject) => {
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM burgers", (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      reoslve(res);
    });
  });
}
```

You can then use it like this

```
app.get(`/`, function async (req, res) {
    const burgers = await selectAll();
    console.log(burgers)

    res.render(`index`, burgers);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selectAll method will not return any value.

query get an lambda callback function as second parameter AND query is asyncron

One way is to return an Promise from selectAll

```
const orm = {
  selectAll(callback) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      connection.query('SELECT * FROM burgers', (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(res)
        }
      })
    })
  },
```

Than you can get your result:

```
app.get(`/`, function (req, res) {
  orm.selectAll().then( burgers => {
    console.log(burgers)
    res.render(`index`, burgers);
  });
});
```